# Chat application erlang ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erlang, chat

Not that I did not find any answers to my doubts but I still wish to clear my confusion over the implementation of a chat server in Erlang in an existing Rails application.

While trying to connect Ruby and Erlang, I experimented with BERT-RPC, Erlectricity and ErlPort.

Considering that its possible to construct a basic chat application in Erlang itself,how do I  seamlessly connect this Erlang app with the Rails app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, The best aproach would be to let erlang serve the chat server itself. You could run your rails app and your reverse proxy would serve your chat server from a specific url.
Also, if you serve your chat application through your rails application, Your chat application speed will be the speed of your rails app.

Comment: But both servers will have to communicate .(e.g spawning a new process when a user session starts will have to be notified by Rails to Erlang.)

Comment: This still seems possible. You just have to have two different interfaces to your application. one from clients and one from the rails server. when a new user comes in your rails server can notify your erlang server to create a new process.